# Can apparmor restrict interpreted languages?

Tags: python, security, apparmor

For interpreted/vm languages(e.g. python, java, shell scripts) can apparmor be set to only confine a particular script or program?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. It's also in use in Ubuntu, especially on the phone.

To get a basic apparmor script, you can use aa-autodep from the apparmor-utils package.

Quick example for python:

```
cat >> ~/myapp << EOF
#! /usr/bin/python
EOF

sudo aa-autodep ~/myapp

cat /etc/apparmor.d/home.<user-name>.myapp
```

This will give you something like:

```
# Last Modified: Mon Feb 24 18:31:50 2014
#include <tunables/global>

/home/sam/myapp flags=(complain) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/python>

  /home/sam/myapp r,
  /usr/bin/python2.7 ix,

}
```

Then you can expand on that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually using ' /usr/bin/python2.7 ix,' is not a good idea.
Since exploited code may execute python from shell, for example:
python -c 'some evil code'.

This definitely not what you want and totally breaks sandbox concept (what apparmor is).

`ix` means inherit same restrictions as parent profile. In this case, i'm not sure if executing external commands under same restrictions as /home/sam/myap is a good idea.

Since we're talking about security, we should ask: why external command/python called from `/home/sam/myapp` should be able to access for read/write/deleting files created by `/home/sam/myapp` or system wide sensitive files? or even create connection to external system? (remember the old case of skype reading unnecessary files under /etc?)

So the more secure solution is use child profile (subprofile) to running external python program

```
#include <tunables/global>

/home/sam/myapp flags=(complain) {
  #include <abstractions/base>


  /home/sam/myapp r,
  /usr/bin/python2.7 Cx -> trusted_domain,

  profile trusted_domain {

   #include <abstractions/....>

   #include <abstraction/python>
   /usr/bin/my-python-app r,
   ... your policy for data, logs, connections, python files...
  }

}
```

Comment: -1. Perhaps you could explain your alternative a bit better? You've explained why the other answer is bad, but not what your answer does differently - which takes this dangerously closet o a code-only answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, `ix` means inherit same restrictions as parent profile. In this case, i'm not sure if executing external commands under same restrictions as `/home/sam/myap` is a good idea.

Comment: Since we're talking about security, we should ask: why external command/python called from `/home/sam/myapp` should be able to access for read/write/deleting files created by `/home/sam/myapp`? or even create connection to external system?

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks for the explanation! Perhaps you could update your answer with this? Then I can reverse my -1.

Answer (score 0):

I think yurii is confused possibly and thinks that "ix" means "unconfined" which would be "Ux" or "ux". I don't see any escape vulnerability here with launching python again either from a shell or subprocess.

More on the execution flags can be found at https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/QuickProfileLanguage